# Spring SAML ServletException

Tags: spring-saml

I've created a weblogic 12c version of the Spring Security SAML sample application.  When I try to run it, I get the following error:

> ]] Root cause of ServletException.
>   weblogic.servlet.jsp.CompilationException: Failed to compile JSP
>   /WEB-INF/security/idpSelection.jsp idpSelection.jsp:1:1: The validator
>   class: "org.apache.taglibs.standard.tlv.JstlCoreTLV" has failed with
>   the following exception: "java.lang.ClassCastException:
>   weblogic.xml.jaxp.RegistrySAXParserFactory cannot be cast to
>   javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory". <%@ page ^-------
>     import="org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.MetadataManager"%>
>   ----------------------------------------------------------------------------^
>
> at
>   weblogic.servlet.jsp.JavelinxJSPStub.reportCompilationErrorIfNeccessary(JavelinxJSPStub.java:244)
>     at
>   weblogic.servlet.jsp.JavelinxJSPStub.compilePage0(JavelinxJSPStub.java:180)
>     at
>   weblogic.servlet.jsp.JavelinxJSPStub.access$000(JavelinxJSPStub.java:50)
>     at
>   weblogic.servlet.jsp.JavelinxJSPStub$1.run(JavelinxJSPStub.java:108)
>     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>     Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
>
> > <[ServletContext@11256322[app:_auto_generated_ear_ module:SAML2Sample
> >     path:null spec-version:3.0]] Problem occurred while serving the error
> >     page. javax.servlet.ServletException:
> >     weblogic.servlet.jsp.CompilationException: Failed to compile JSP
> >     /error.jsp error.jsp:1:1: The validator class:
> >     "org.apache.taglibs.standard.tlv.JstlCoreTLV" has failed with the
> >     following exception: "java.lang.ClassCastException:
> >     weblogic.xml.jaxp.RegistrySAXParserFactory cannot be cast to
> >     javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory". <%@ page
> >     import="java.io.StringWriter" %>
>
> ^---------------------------------------^
>
> at
>   weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:306)
>     at
>   weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.onAddToMapException(ServletStubImpl.java:483)
>     at
>   weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:372)
>     at
>   weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:243)
>     at
>   weblogic.servlet.internal.RequestDispatcherImpl.invokeServlet(RequestDispatcherImpl.java:587)
>     Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace Caused By:
>   weblogic.servlet.jsp.CompilationException: Failed to compile JSP
>   /error.jsp error.jsp:1:1: The validator class:
>   "org.apache.taglibs.standard.tlv.JstlCoreTLV" has failed with the
>   following exception: "java.lang.ClassCastException:
>   weblogic.xml.jaxp.RegistrySAXParserFactory cannot be cast to
>   javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory". <%@ page
>   import="java.io.StringWriter" %>
>
> ^---------------------------------------^
>
> at
>   weblogic.servlet.jsp.JavelinxJSPStub.reportCompilationErrorIfNeccessary(JavelinxJSPStub.java:244)
>     at
>   weblogic.servlet.jsp.JavelinxJSPStub.compilePage0(JavelinxJSPStub.java:180)
>     at
>   weblogic.servlet.jsp.JavelinxJSPStub.access$000(JavelinxJSPStub.java:50)
>     at
>   weblogic.servlet.jsp.JavelinxJSPStub$1.run(JavelinxJSPStub.java:108)
>     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>     Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
>   >

Any ideas on what's causing the CompilationException?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

For those of you who may run into this in the future, changing the scope of the dependency (javax.servlet/jstl) from compile to provided in the pom.xml fixed my problem.